# EntityFramework not Adding table in edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, edmx

I am using `MVC 5`, `Visual Studio 2013` ,`Entity Framework 6.0`.

When I try to create edmx then one table is always missing from edmx.I have tried serveral times by deleting ,eding edmx and creating new but nothing worked.

Also as mentioned in the image below , i have clearly checked the table,but when the edmx is created it is missing.

**Edit:**
The table name which is not adding is `Media`, when I rename this table to some other name then this works.I don't know what is the problem with this name.

[image]

Comment: Your Media table may have some relationship with other tables, which may cause a conflict.

Comment: @JeffChen when I renamed Media to Mediatemp this works,its causing problem with Media name